# if domain a function is finite, can we conclude the range is finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f : A \to B $ is a function. We are given that $Dom f \subset A  $ is finite: that is there is a bijection $g : Dom f \to \{1,...,n \} $. I want to show that $Range f $ is also finite.

I know this is trivial but I would like to know how can we explicitly exhibit a bijection from $range f $ to $\{1,...,m \}, say $

Comment: FYI, when you write $f: A\to B$, that is implicitly saying that all of $A$ is the domain.

Comment: @Nishant Not necessarily; it's a convention and it's apparent that Anonaki is using a different one, where $f\colon A\to B$ means $f$ is a function defined on a subset $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ of $A$.

Comment: @egreg Would you know some sources where the notation $f:A\to B$ allows that the domain of $f$ is not $A$? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we can enumerate the domain of $f$ as $\{a_1, a_2,...a_k\}$. Then The range of $f$ is $\{f(a_1),f(a_2)..f(a_m)\}$ (all distinct) where $m \le k$.Then  the map $h\circ g$ gives the desired map where $g : f(a_i) \to a_i$ for all $i=1,2..m$ and then the map $h: a_i \to i$